# Deletar uma Imagem especifica de um Arquivo

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, delete

Atualmente estou a trabalhar num novo projeto, usando Codeigniter, é a minha primeira experiencia e não encontro grande ajuda, quero que o utilizador possa eliminar uma foto escolhida por ele da sua pasta, O controlador: 
`

```
public function delete()
    {
        delete_files('C:\wamp64\www\uploads\_back');
    }`
```

A view:`

```
{imagesback}
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        {ver}
                                    <img src="{path}" style="width: 100%; height: 100px;">
                                    <p>{name}</p>
                                    <button name="nameimagetodelete" onclick="do_delete('{name}')"></button>
                                    </div>
                                    {/imagesback}
```

`

e o  JavaScript`<

```
script type="text/javascript">
    function do_delete(name){
        var r = confirm("You sure?");
        if (r == true) 
        {
            window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('admin/delete');?>?name="+name;
        }
        else
        {
            x = "Action canceled";
            alert(x);
        }
    }
</script>
```

`

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com questions english

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Desculpe não entendi! Prefere a pergunta em português?

Comment: Sim claro vou traduzir! Agradeço desde ja a ajuda!

Comment: @GabrielGomes o link [**editar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/305408/edit) fica abaixo das tags, para formatar o código, basta selecionar ele e apertar o atalho `CTRL+K` ou no boão `{}` no editor, aproveite faça o [**Tour**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona o site.

Comment: ja está editado @NoobSaibot

Answer (score 0):

uma vez que não indicas qual o erro que estás a obter, torna se mais dificil ajudar.

mas pode ser por falta do carregamento da lib do condingniter responsalvel pelos ficheiros

poderás faze lo adicionado a seguinte linha de código ao teu controlador 
$this->load->helper('file');

depois podes estar com problemas por estar a usar o caminho absoluto do ficheiro

Comment: Sim já está resolvido, alem de faltar a lib também tinha vários outros problemas que acabaram por ficar resolvidos.

Comment: finaliza o tikect